# Azure AD B2C authorization code flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, httpwebrequest, azure-active-directory, httpwebresponse

I build xamarin mobile app that has asp.net core web api as backend and I want to protected it using oauth2.0 authorization code flow.

Using this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code#1-get-an-authorization-code

I'm trying to get authorization code. I send request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_domain_name}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? endpoint with query parameters:

```
client_id - id of added application to azure ad b2c 
response_type=code 
redirect_uri=redirect url for native application from added application to azure ad b2c 
response_mode=query 
scope=client id value and "offline_access" separated by whitespace state=test_0001 
p=B2C_1_CommonLogin - sign in policy for local accounts
```

From response I get html page to login as string. I parse login page string to get ctx, flowToken and canary tokens to send request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_domain_name}/login endpoint to get authorization code. 
To do post request I use following formatting:

```
string postData = string.Format($@"login={email}&passwd={password}&ctx={ctx}&flowToken={flowToken}&canary={canary}&dssoToken=");
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
```

And write data array to request stream.

Then I call GetResponse on request object and get "Bad request" as response without details. 
Also in HttpWebReponse object I see ResponseUrl that points to:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant_domain_name}/oauth2/authresp?
and contains id_token, state and session_state parameters in query.

Could you advice anything?

Answer (score 0):

Did you using the code to simulate the progress of sign-in? After you enter the username/password to post it to the Azure login endpoint, the Azure AD should give **302 response** which would redirect the URL as you passed in the request.

And you are able to find the code in the **location** header then you can use the code exchange the token as the document mentioned. Here is a successful response for your reference:
[image]

To narrow down the issue, I suggest that you try the request in the broswer and caputer it using the Fiddler.

Comment: Yes, I tried to simulate it but it's not so easy as I thought. I can reproduce same error(Bad request) in browser running sign-in policy. Because my sign-in policy is for native app after login Edge tries to open some app and if on this stage you refresh browser page and login on more time you will get Bad request. I guess it's protection from something. And my requests in code blocked by the same protection.